# Symmetric real matrix $A$ with $0$ as the only eigenvalue, does this imply $A=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a real symmetric $n \times n$ matrix ($n$ a positive integer).
Let $0$ be the only eigenvalue of $A$. Does this imply $A=0$?

Comment: You don't need to write $n\space x\space n$; you can write $n\times n$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  This is easy to see if you note that the diagonalization of $A$ produces $0$.

Comment: Yes of course! Thank you!